# How to run a JAVA Fx application along with other components through .exe file

Tags: java, sockets, javafx, netbeans

I have created a JavaFx application in NetBeans. I just created a sample textfield page where user enters Ip address and port number so that I will be connecting to the server on local host written in basic JAVA socket library. Mean while in a parallel thread I am starting a JAVA TCP server in the same application which receives data from a tcp client. Now the problem is when I run through NetBeans the server is able to start happily. But when I made a .exe file using launch4j only the TCp client is starting which user has filled the details in UI. And after that the next process is not starting up.

But it is working absolutely fine when running through NetBeans. I made several .exe files through launch4j but I never included GUI part into the .exe files. Is this causing any issue? The GUI only takes the IP address and port number from the user and when the user clicks on OK button the UI page closes and remaining process has to start. But when I run through .exe file it is not running. Please help me with this. When I built my project with netbeans I am seeing the output as:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 12 files to D:\NetBeansProjects\QTSimulator\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: D:\NetBeansProjects\QTSimulator\dist
Copying 12 files to D:\NetBeansProjects\QTSimulator\dist\lib
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Launching <fx:deploy> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
jfx-deployment-script:
jfx-deployment:
jar:
jfx-rebuild:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)
```

Am I doing any wrong here. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans has bugs with the JAVAFx applications. You can run through NetBeans IDE but when you run through the Jar we get these kind of issues. Try installing Eclipse and import the project and build. Later make a runnable jar and then launch it. It works